# Do I need to include documents about my friend when he is not my sponsor?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork

I want to go on a two-weeks holiday.

My company will sponsor me. They have made a hotel reservation for me, but I have a friend in the UK, who has agreed to show me around the country on my arrival.

Please note that he didn't have any hand in sponsoring my trip. My question is **do I still need to including his documents in my supporting documents?**

Comment: If the friend is just someone you meet up with, rather than someone whose support you need to make the trip, you don't need to document their circumstances. That being said, the fact that **your employer** is paying for your **holiday** may raise an eyebrow or two. This is not forbidden (unless it's a way of evading tax in your home country), but it's unusual enough that they may try to imagine ways it could be a cover for something that _is_ forbidden on an ordinary visitor visa -- such as working while you're in the UK.

Comment: @Queen Your company is sponsoring a holiday? I agree with Henning Makholm - very unusual, you’ll need to explain why and have confirmation of the reason from the company, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

No, these documents don't need included. In your application/on arrival you can mention you will be meeting a friend and tell them his name and address but more information isn't required unless explicitly asked for as the friend isn't your sponsor.